# Debug Web Service SOAP en produccion

Tags: java, soap

Tengo un *webservice* publicado y funcionando en producción.
Me he bajado el código fuente del repositorio para poder depurarlo, sin embargo, no consigo hacer pruebas desde localhost, si cambio la url

```
soap:address location="http//www.servidor/clientesCompra/firmaWebService" />
```

por esta otra

```
soap:address location="http//localhost:8080/clientesCompra/firmaWebService" />
```

No consigo que funcione, ni siquiera levanto/publico el *WSDL* con la nueva URL.

Lo que pretendo es hacer llamadas al *webservice* y que al hacerlo se detenga en los puntos de debug de mi código.

He probado a arrancar el servidor (Wildfly8) en modo *debug* pero, cuando hago peticiones desde, por ejemplo SoapUi a la url `http//www.servidor/clientesCompra/firmaWebService`, no se detiene en mi código y cuando apunto a  `http//localhost:8080/clientesCompra/firmaWebService` no llegan las peticiones, me lanza un error 404.

He probado a copiar el *WSDL* entero y dejarlo en la ruta `src/test/resources`, también en `src/main/wbapp/WEB-INF` y en `web-resources/MATA-INF`,
pero nada de esto funciona.

Gracias por vuestras aportaciones.

Comment: Según me acuerdo, el servidor donde esta desplegado el servicio dede ser iniciado en modo debug, y el código fuente debe ser attachado al puerto debug del Servidor de aplicaciones, de esa forma cuando se consuma el servicio entra a los puntos de debug marcados en el código.

Comment: A la URL que publicas le falta el `:` luego de `http`. Debiera lucir así: `http://abc/`

Comment: tienes razón, disculpa la errata, pero ese no es el problema. En mis pruebas realizo la petición con la url correcta.

Comment: isaac gracias por tu aporte. No tengo acceso al servidor de producción, ni tampoco puedo configurar en él la opción de debug remoto. Por lo que no puedo arrancar en debug el servidor donde está desplegado. Lo intento desplegar hacer en otro servidor local y al cambiar la url sucede las peticiones no llegan. Es decir, intento hacer debug en el código de un webservice sin tener acceso al servidor en el que está desplegado, peros si al código fuente.